# Absolute-value bar with a gap in the middle

Tags: code, delimiters

I am trying to typeset some Isar code such as [image: isabelle_code] in LaTeX (in an ad-hoc fashion).
However, I can't find anything like this symbol
[image: abs_with_gap] and I don't know what it's called. In Isabelle you can write it as `\<bar>` but the LaTeX `\bar` is something different I believe.

Comment: Isn't that symbol the same as the pipe? It is just typeset like that in some fonts. Otherwise look in the symbols list (texdoc symbols-a4), there might be an explicit symbols called something like textbrokenbar

Comment: \textbrokenbar seems to give me the right symbol, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The meaning is probably the same as `|... |` but you can look through the symbols list (texdoc symbols-a4) for something like textbrokenbar.